# Issues escaping string in batch command

Tags: batch-file, escaping

I am trying to get a variable, put that in between two set strings and finally open the concatenated string in Chrome. There is, however, part of the string that I am having issues with which I am presuming is due to the usage of special characters.

```
@echo off
set loc=%1
set link1=https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from geo.places where text='
set link2='&format=json  
set linkdone=%link1%%loc%%link2%

"chrome.exe" "%linkdone%"
```

`link2` (`'&format=json`) is giving issues here, when I echo after setting it. It is an empty string and the batch goes on to echo `invalid drive specification` which is due to the erroneous reading of `link2` I would assume.

I have tried escaping it as `^'^&format^=json` but it does not seem to work. The rest of the code (notably `link1` without escapechars) seems to work fine.

Comment: There is no escaping necessary if you are following the following syntax: `set "VAR=value"` (note the quotes); since the final command line also contains the variable value quoted, there is still no need for escaping; special characters lose their particular meaning when placed within `""`; finally, instead of `%1` you should state `%~1`...

Comment: Not sure whether you have to `%`-escape some characters within the query `select * from geo.places where text=` for the browser, like `%20` for _space_, or `%3D` for `=`, for example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To properly quote the argument to `set` you have to quote the *entire* argument, this includes the variable name:

```
set "link2='&format=json"
```

Note also that normal variable expansion is simple text substitution while a command is parsed, so you will have to properly escape every occurrence of that variable afterwards, such as

```
set "linkdone=%link1%%loc%%link2%"
```

In your case I'd probably opt for something a lot simpler, though:

```
@chrome "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from geo.places where text='%1'&format=json"
```

No need to fiddle with variables when unsure how to escape and quote in this variant.

Comment: Cheers mate, the last one worked perfectly! I'm not too familiar with batch commands yet so I wasn't sure whether pasting a variable in a string would cause issues.

Comment: Causes a lot fewer issues than what you tried. It can be made to work, but unless you actually need the pieces for something else I wouldn't usually bother.

Answer (score 0):

```
set "link2='^&format=json"
```

should set `link2` as you require (you don't say...)

With an argument of `hello`, `echo`ing the "chrome" line produces

> ```
> "chrome.exe" "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from geo.places where text='hello'&format=json"
> ```

for me - and produces no error report.

Comment: You don't need the `^`  in there.

Comment: @Joey : Umm, perhaps you should try it...fails without the caret for me (win 10)

Comment: Same error message, tried putting quotation marks around link1 too, no difference.

Comment: I pasted the code directly from my test. For me, it generates no error. Perhaps you are using a different OS? Are you cutting-and-pasting the code? Which editor are you using (A WP or Notepad have been known to produce strange errors as the application tries to "format" the code)?

Answer (score 0):

Escaping the `&` in a `set` command has failed for me and I confess I don't know why

So I propose a workaround for this. Use `__amp__` to replace `&` in the `set`. Replace it by the actual `&` afterwards (here escaping works!)

```
@echo off
set loc=%1
set link1=https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from geo.places where text='
set link2='__amp__format=json
set linkdone=%link1%%loc%%link2%
echo %linkdone:__amp__=^&%
```

result with `the_loc` as a parameter:

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from geo.places where text='the_loc'&format=json
```

(BTW no need to escape single quote, which has no special meaning in batch)